# Can I build and compile an app built for jail broken iOS and run as a development app on my device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, jailbreak

Just a quick q about iOS development..

I'd love to be able to run a certain game emulator on my iPad..

If it's released under open source is there any thing stopping me from compiling it and running it in an emulator or getting a provisioning profile and running it on my device?

Do jailbroken apps tend to use libraries that wont run on a vanilla copy of iOS?

I.e. Do they patch the kernel to get full control of the video controller etc..

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: I think the jailbroken apps can utilize `eglibc` or `glibc`, as when I jailbroke me iPod Touch, I remember looking over the installed packages, and remember seeing something along the lines of `glibc`. In short, I think if the app is self-sufficient, you probably could.

Comment: Cool.. Thanks :) the only thing is I heard that some emus may drop down to assembler code for speed... Which is a big no-no on the apple side of things.. Hmmmm.. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, Apple will *definitely* let you run low-level code. When I think of emulator, I'm thinking Nintendo. Why would you need to have *more* speed?

Comment: You'd be suprised how hungry some of those emus are.. by the way i'd mark you as the correct answer but its a comment so i cant :P

Comment: Okay, I'll post it as an answer. I've never done much with emulating, so I can't say much on that topic. The last emulator I ran was to run Quake ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the jailbroken apps can utilize `eglibc` or `glibc`, as when I jailbroke me iPod Touch, I remember looking over the installed packages, and remember seeing something along the lines of `glibc`.

In short, I think if the app is self-sufficient, you probably could package it with XCode, but if it requires some low-level APIs and libraries, you're out of luck.